# why is the return of the program not good?

Tags: python, return

I'm new to python and there's a video on Youtube that I watched. I do the exact same code as he but mine doesn't work and I don' understand why.
Here's the code:

```
MAX_LINES = 3

def deposit():
    while True:
        amount = input("What would you like to deposit? $")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if amount > 0:
                break
            else:
                print("Amount must be greater than 0. ")
        else:
            print("Please enter a number. ")

    return amount
   
def get_number_of_lines():
     while True:
        lines = input("Enter the number of lines to bet on (1-" + str(MAX_LINES) + ")? ")
        if lines.isdigit():
            lines = int(lines)
            if 1 <= lines <= MAX_LINES:
                break
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid number of lines. ")
        else:
            print("Please enter a number. ")
            
    return lines
```

There are 3 problems.

1. Unindent amount does not match previous indent. I have no idea what does that mean
2. "return" can be used only within a function. As far as I'm concerned I'm using it in the function, copied the first function then pasted it into the second function and somehow it doesn't work
3. "lines" is not defined. What dou you mean it's not defined, I define it in the first line of the function
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=th4OBktqK1I
   This video's code what I'm trying to do

I appreciate any help!

I just simply don't understand why it works in one and not the other

Comment: As the error says, your indentation is messed up.  Your `while True:` (which defines the indentation level for the body of the function) is indented with 5 spaces and your `return lines` is indented with 4.   Use a better editor to write your code; an IDE will highlight the indentation to make mistakes like this obvious (I just pasted your code into VSCode and it showed me the mismatch instantly), or just use a plain text editor and use tabs instead of spaces.  As long as you're consistent it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have one space too much in front of `while True` in function `get_number_of_lines()`.
2. Yes used in functions to return value
3. Because function don't get inside `while` loop (because of indent problem), `lines` is never defined, probably this was the problem.

So try fix indent and run again

Comment: Okay, but there is one more problem left. When I run the program somehow the first function does not work. As you can see the input is "What would you like to deposit? $" But that question doesn't show up in the terminal only the second function's question. What could cause that?

Comment: Obviously, I called both of the functions in the main like this:
def main():
    balance = deposit()
    lines = get_number_of_lines()
    print(balance, lines)

Comment: @kristof this might be your console problem, how do you run your python code?
check this out, your code works
https://www.online-python.com/yFsYQJZ5gD

Comment: Now, it works. I run + build of the terminal again and it's good now. But I wonder if that was the problem.
What do you mean by how I run my code?

Comment: I mean how you start your program? Are you using build in terminal like in the youtube video with command C://xx/python.exe <your_file>? Or maybe you are using windows cmd.exe? Or something else? I am asking because different consoles work differently, and there is a possibility that this message "What would you like to deposit? $", didn't show up just because of console you are using. If it happen again just copy your code to online interpreter and run. If in online interpreter everything is ok, I believe you can ignore the problem on your pc (if it is not breaking your main code result)

Comment: On some consoles you have to "clear input", because the key that you pressed before running code, is entered automatically. For instance you pressed Ctrl + V to paste filename to console, and this "V" is secretly waiting for `input("What would you like to deposit? $")` code, and when you start program it is entered automatically so it looks like `input("What would you like to deposit? $")` is skipped, but it is not. I can't help you with your console and system, but just want to show some possible reasons

Comment: I use a build in terminal, but it's finally works so I'm happy.
Thanks for your help mate!